# Errors :Issue with reading text file in class I created

Tags: java, class, text, compiler-errors, java-7

When I run my program(BaseballStatsClient) i am receiving errors: cannont find symbol for the team name, max, and min

UPDATE:

I am now having an issue with what i believe is the reading of the text file, the output values for team name are tars.txt and for the max and min are 0.0 when i run the program. I think in the first code i havent read the text file properly

Txt file :

```
Tars 
0.592
0.427
0.194
0.445
0.127
0.483
0.352
0.190
0.335
0.207
0.116
0.387
0.243
0.225
0.401
0.382
0.556
0.319
0.475
0.279
```

Here is the class file i created, i think there is an issue with how it reads the text file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseballStats {

  private String fileName;
  private String teamName;
  private double [] battingAverage;


  public BaseballStats ( String fileName ) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    boolean firstLine = true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(fileName);
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = input.nextLine();
      if (firstLine) {
        setTeamName (line);
        firstLine = false;
        continue;
      }
      int i=0;
      while(input.hasNext()) {
        battingAverage[i] = input.nextDouble();
        i++;      
      }
    }
  }

  public String getTeamName( ) {
    return teamName;
  }

  public void setTeamName( String newTeamName ) {
    teamName=newTeamName;
  }

  public double findMaxAverage( ) {
    double max =battingAverage[0];
    for ( int i =1; i < battingAverage.length; i++) {
      if(battingAverage[i] >max)
        max= battingAverage[i];
    }
    return max;
  }
  public double findMinAverage( ) {
    double min =battingAverage[0];
    for ( int i =1; i < battingAverage.length; i++) {
      if(battingAverage[i] < min)
        min= battingAverage[i];
    }
    return min;
  }    
  public double spread( ) {
    //returns the difference between the highest and lowest batting averages
  }
  public int goodPlayers( ) {     
    //returns the number of players with an average higher than .300
  }
  public String toString( ) {  
   // returns a String containing the team name followed by all the batting averages  formatted to three decimal places.
  }
}
```

And this is the program i am running:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseballStatsClient {  
  public static void main( String [] args ) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in );
    System.out.println("What is the name of the file you would like to find the statistics of?");
    String fileName = scan.next( );

    BaseballStats newTeam = new BaseballStats(fileName);
    System.out.println("The " + newTeam.getTeamName() + " statistics are:");
    System.out.println("Highest Batting Average: " + newTeam.findMaxAverage( ));
    System.out.println("Lowest Batting Average: " + newTeam.findMinAverage( ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newTeam.getTeamName( );
System.out.println("The " + teamName + " statistics are:");
newTeam.findMaxAverage( );
System.out.println("Highest Batting Average: " + max);
newTeam.findMinAverage( );
System.out.println("Lowest Batting Average: " +min);
```

You haven't defined define them and trying to print them.

Define variables with  returned values.

like

```
   String teamName =newTeam.getTeamName( );
   System.out.println("The " + teamName + " statistics are:");
```

And the same for remaining `min` and `max` variables too.

Moreover you can directly do

```
 System.out.println("The " + newTeam.getTeamName() + " statistics are:");
```

And beware of `newTeam`, may `null`.

Comment: Or just `System.out.println("The " + newTeam.getTeamName( ) + " statistics are:");`, if no validation is required (which in that case might be best to do inside the BaseballStats class.).

Comment: ok thanks that solved the error but it outputs for team name tars.txt which is the name of the file and the max and min are outputted at 0.0

Comment: i have updated the code, i think there is an issue reading the text file in the first code

Comment: @user2985542 Look at the if else condition in your reading file. That might be the problem.

Comment: Im looking but i dont know what im suppose to see

Comment: in your  BaseballStats   class  write `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));`  not `Scanner input = new Scanner(fileName);`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the return value.

You can do something like this:

```
String returnValue =newTeam.getTeamName( );
System.out.println("The value is " + returnValue);
```

Comment: ok i have fixed that but i think there is an issue in how the text file is being read because the max and min were outputted at 0.0 and the team name was the file name